# Chatbot for question/answer with load_qa_chain fucntion, chat history exceed token limit

Tags: python, chatbot, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I just followed the example in the langchain documentation to create a basic QA chatbot.

It works fine, but after a enough questions, chat history seem to become too big for the prompt and I get this error :

```
This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens, however you requested 4107 tokens (4054 in your prompt; 73 for the completion). Please reduce your prompt; or completion length.
```

Here's the code :

```
    with open("./reponse_a_la_vie.txt") as f:
    reponse_a_la_vie = f.read()
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)
texts = text_splitter.split_text(reponse_a_la_vie)

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

docsearch = Chroma.from_texts(
    texts, embeddings, metadatas=[{"source": i} for i in range(len(texts))]
)



Template
template = """You are a chatbot having a conversation with a human.

Given the following extracted parts of a long document and a question, create a final answer.

{context}

{chat_history}
Human: {human_input}
Chatbot:"""

prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["chat_history", "human_input", "context"], template=template
)
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", input_key="human_input")
chain = load_qa_chain(
    OpenAI(temperature=1, max_tokens=1000), chain_type="stuff", memory=memory, prompt=prompt
)

def generate_response(query):
    docs = docsearch.similarity_search(query)
    return chain({"input_documents": docs, "human_input": query}, return_only_outputs=True)['output_text']
```

How could I avoid that without altering the memory?

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known limitation of the feature, it will grow the size of the input implicitly until it gets bigger than the max number of tokens supported and generates the token error you just faced.

In short, that memory feature would work only with small number of interactions.

If you want to work around that issue one alternative is the usage of the feature named : ConversationTokenBufferMemory(llm=llm,max_token_limit=<nbToken>)

Here it will support memory of the discussion until it grows up to nbToken tokens value. You could try 512 or 2048 for instance.
For additional inputs in the memory, above the token_limit, old entries will go away while most recent will remain.

Src:https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/types/token_buffer

Ideally you save your growing memory in a dedicated db, like redis, then you can remember way longer conversations.

Src:https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/agent_with_memory_in_db